# Image Post on Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

In my application. I successfully post a image on my Facebook wall (image type JPEG Type). It's work fine in Simulator and and Device also.

But the problem is that When I Capture Image from my iPhone or select an image from library which is captured by camera. It is not Posted on Facebook Wall.

on other hand when i choose any jpeg image (downloaded by internet) from my iPhone library. It post on wall.

In my opinion there is image format problem. Please Guide me

Thanks

My code is here.

```
-(IBAction)clickButtonClicked
{
//    For link post

NSString *Message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing Iphone App : \"http://www.google.com\" "];    


DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance]; 

UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]init ];

image= obj.imgFinalImage;

NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


[params1 setObject:image forKey:@"source"];
[params1 setObject:Message forKey:@"message"];

NSString *post=@"/me/photos";


[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:post andParams:params1 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"Invitation Send Sucessfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];


}
```

Comment: One question, why do you allocate an `UIImage` here: `UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]init ];` when on the next line you assign the the `obj.imgFinalImage` to image. You are just leaking the image variable here.

Comment: @rckoenes. Yes you are right. I many time changes my code.. so i forget that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you pass the image in the wrong property:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    sobj.imgFinalImage, @"picture",
                    Message, @"caption",
                     nil];

[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                   andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                  andDelegate:self];
```

Then make sure you implement the delegate of Facbook request to check if the image is uploaded.

With the graph API you can't send a `UIImage` directly, you need to send the `NSData` representation of the `UIImage`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSData *imageDate = UIImagePNGRepresentation(obj.imgFinalImage);

[params1 imageDate forKey:@"source"];
[params1 setObject:Message forKey:@"message"];

NSString *post=@"/me/photos";


[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:post andParams:params1 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: my images downloaded by internet already posted on Facebook wall. but image captured by camera is not posted. now i am trying your code.

Comment: rckoenes again you are Right :). i only change @"picture" and it posted on my wall. But i still confused. when i use @"source" my image also uploaded on Wall. but only those who i downloaded from internet?.

Comment: When you posted the `UIImage` as source my guess is that the facebook SDK did not correctly transformed the object to a jpg/png. Guess you work lucky when you used some jpg's. if you see my edit if changed the code to use the graph API, where I transform the `UIImage` in to `NSData` object containing the `UIImage` as a png.