# Facebook Share Photo: giving me (facebookErrDomain error 368.)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

When I try to share a screenshot of my iOS app on Facebook I get the following response :

*FB error: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 368.)*

Post Photo Code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary
                               dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fbImage, @"picture", fbContent, @"caption"
                               ,nil];

[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload" andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I take the screenshot using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The thing is, I am able to post the screenshot in my other app using the exact same code. So that would mean it is not solely because of fb server issues? Is there something I might be missing?

*Edit*
I am also using FBConnect in the same project for sharing text using:

```
  [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

with params as:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                           url, @"link",
                           name, @"name",
                           caption, @"caption",
                           desc, @"description",
                           nil];
```

And it works absolutely fine.

Comment: can you please put your code here :-(

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. Code specific to which function?

Comment: May be this question is helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797224/image-post-on-facebook

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I found out the cause of error. After I printed a log of the error description, it mentioned that Facebook doesn't allow spam links. Turns out I had misspelled the link in the caption for the photo post. After rectifying it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments. I found out the cause of my error. After I printed a log of the error localized description:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"FB error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

it mentioned facebookErrDomain error 368 and after printing the whole description:

```
    NSLog(@"FB error: %@", [error description]);
```

it was written that Facebook doesn't allow spam links.

Turns out I had misspelled the link in the caption for the photo post. After rectifying it worked smoothly.

So if you get **facebookErrDomain error 368.** check the data you are sending in Params. If it contains a link you haven't created yet or any other data that can be thought to be as spam, delete it or comment it out and the error should disappear.